# Salesforce : INVALID_TYPE: This type of object is not available for this organization faultcode=sf

Tags: visualforce, metadata-api

I am trying to update a apex class in salesforce by using metadata api but recieving this error when I call the update_x method.

I have achieved to get the zip file package of the desired class and unzipped it by using JSZip, now when I try to update the whole package it gives me the error.

Also I have red it on the net that you have to get the zip back together to save the results successfully, but I am not sure how to again make a zip of the class, class-meta and package.xml files.

Comment: Is it production or sandbox? Productions (except special cases like Developer Edition) don't allow to write classes & triggers directly in them. If that call is for simple making changes to the class then I guess you'd have to use deploy call instead?

Comment: @eyescream its developer org

Comment: Did you tried deploying package without unzip it?

Comment: @regal and @ eyescream thanks for the advice deploy has done the trick.. thanks